# How to stop variables from connecting

Tags: javascript, arrays

Suppose you have the following code:

```
var array = [1];
var array2 = array;

array2.push(2);

alert(array);
```

This will alert "1,2", even though I clearly declared `array` as `[1]`, and then did no changes to it. It's like `array` and `array2` gets connected, and every change I do to `array2` affects `array`. I simply want to declare `array2` with the same value as `array`, not connect them.

Why does this happen and how to prevent it?

Thanks in advance!

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u7t1buLb/1/)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that array2 is pointing on array.

what you want is:

```
var array2 = array.slice(0);
```

This really creates a copy of "array" and does not let the variable array2 point on "array".

Answer (score 1):

It's because arrays and objects in JS are "passed by reference" (actually a copy of reference), not value (as it happens with primitives). There are many ways to do it, one of them being concatting an empty array:

```js
var array = [1];
var array2 = array.concat([]);

array2.push(2);

alert(array);    // 1
alert(array2);   // 1,2
```

See some nice answers here: [Does Javascript pass by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104494/does-javascript-pass-by-reference)

Answer (score 1):

Befor all , in Javascript an **array** is an **Object**
so the array variable is pointing to an in array (that you created `[1]`) that has an adresse in the memory (for example @1234abc). So the variable array it self is a pointer that points to an array.

You did var `array2 = array`
so array2 will point to the same adress in the memory (to the same object).

In other words, **array2 is array** they are pointing to the same object.

To get what you want, you have to create a new array and assign the same values of array1, this is called cloning.
You can do it with this trick `var array2 = array.slice(0);`

Answer (score 0):

`array2` is a reference to the original array, so if you modify it, the original will change too.

You´ll have to set `array2`'s value to array.slice(), which clones the original and gives you a new reference.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of concept [Pass by reference](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~myers/c++/notes/references.html). Internally both the variables are pointing to same memory location. So, when you change one variable that will effect other variables as well. Try `slice()` method if you intend to copy only values but not reference as it is. :)